# Setting up Emacs as an external editor on windows 10

Tags: buffers, microsoft-windows, files

Apologies if this has been asked multiple times already, haven't found a useful answer.

I am trying to use Emacs as an external editor on two separate applications in windows 10, one is a notes app (Joplin), the other is a 3D software, by typing the path to the `file.exe` of that editor. Both allow you to set up the external editor of your choice. If I use Sublime Text it works straight off the bat, whereby I:

- open what I need to modify in the application
- use Sublime to modify that text, save when I'm done, close, and the text gets updated in the application.

I can't get this to happen with Emacs. I am assuming that Emacs is not overwriting the temp file it is editing, somehow. What am I doing wrong, is it possible to use Emacs as an external editor for other applications?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you tried to do with Emacs (more useful than to clarify what you do with Sublime) and what happens instead of what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to use emacs as an editor with other applications which allow people to open text in an editor (Sublime in this case), save it, and then see it updated in the application. For example, in Houdini, a 3D software, I can type code in an external editor (Sublime works, emacs does not), modify, save... and see it update in the application (Houdini). When I use emacs, it doesn't work. I could add a picture, it would make it easier to understand. Is there a way to add images to messages here?

Comment: Please update your question rather than add detail in comments since comments aren't always visible.  Also please clarify *how* you told Houdini to use Emacs, and in what way it "doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, again. Apologies, I've never posted in this forum before: 1) How do I update instead of comment? 2) How can I add pictures? Thanks.

Comment: Just click `edit` to update your post.  For images, not sure (I don't like images, so I've never had to do that), but if you click on the `?` in the edit box it seems like it might give you some ideas.